# How to Load ID and Name parallely to One combo box at same time in C# .net

Tags: c#

I want answer in C# language and .Net framework

Comment: What do you mean by ID and Name ?

Comment: Please give sufficient details with the question when asking so and also give proper formatting... It will help you to get the help of others...

Answer (score 2):

```
var items =
    new[]
        {
            new { Id = 1, Name = "Test1" },
            new { Id = 2, Name = "Test2" },
        };

comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
comboBox1.DataSource = items;
```

[Edited] Thanks to Homam for the pointing out redundant `Item`.

Comment: Without `Item` it's OK too. `new { Id = 1, Name = "Test1 }`

Comment: @Homam - you're right, thank you. Updated.